# Quotient of line bundles is flat

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field, $C$ a smooth, projective, connected curve over $k$ and $T$ a $k$-scheme. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a line bundle on $C\times_{speck}T$.
Let

$0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{C\times T}\xrightarrow[\text{}]{\text{s}} \mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{F}/ \mathcal{O}_{C\times T}\rightarrow 0$

be a short exact sequence such that $s_t: \mathcal{O}_{C\times t}\rightarrow\mathcal{F}_{\mid C\times t}$ is an injection for all $t$ in $T$.

Let $f:C\times T\rightarrow T$ be the projection.

I would like to show that $\mathcal{F}/ \mathcal{O}_{C\times T}$ is flat over $T$. Does someone have an idea how to show this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{O}_{T,t}$ be the local ring at $t\in T$.  Then we want to show that $\mathcal{F_y}/\mathcal{O}_{C\times T,y}$ is flat over this ring, where $y\in C\times t$.

It is well known that to check flatness of a coherent module $M$ over a Noetherian local ring $R$, it suffices to show that $Tor_1(M,k(R))=0$, where $k(R)$ is the residue field.  So we want to show that $Tor_1(\mathcal{F_y}/\mathcal{O}_{C\times T,y},k(t))=0$.

We have the exact sequence:
$$
0\to \mathcal{O}_{C\times T,y}\to \mathcal{F_y}\to
\mathcal{F_y}/\mathcal{O}_{C\times T,y}\to 0
$$
Tensoring with $k(t)$ gives:
$$
0\to Tor_1(\mathcal{F_y}/\mathcal{O}_{C\times T,y},k(t))\to (\mathcal{O}|_{C\times t})_y\xrightarrow{s_t}(\mathcal{F}|_{C\times t})_y
$$
where the sequence begins with 0 because $\mathcal{F}$ is flat over $C\times T$ and $f$ is flat (because $C\to k$ is).  Since $s_t$ is injective, by exactness we get $Tor_1(\mathcal{F_y}/\mathcal{O}_{C\times T,y},k(t))=0$ which is what we wanted.

Comment: Thank you very much! I haven't studied Tor yet so I didn't know that it is such a nice tool to check flatness.